# Yo unaware of installed generators

Tags: npm, yeoman

I just installed Yeoman and some generators. However, because the `/usr/lib` folder is protected, I chose to change the prefix of the location where NPM installs its packages.

Right now, everything is getting installed under `~/.node`. I also changed my `$PATH` and added `~/.node/bin`. However, when I execute `yo <name of generator>`, I get the following:

```
Error node 

You don't seem to have a generator with the name node installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 0 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

As you can read here, it's telling me there are 0 registered generators, but I installed them correctly (and it completed without errors). I'm able to find the installed generators, for example `~/.node/lib/node_modules/generator-node` exists and when I execute the following command:

```
npm list -g
```

I can find the generators that I installed (so I assume it isn't a problem with npm).

So I think Yeoman (or Yo to be more precisely) is unaware of the generators being installed in the custom folder, but I haven't found any way to configure this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to adding it to your path, you should also set a `NODE_PATH` environment variable. The [yeoman/generator code](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/34441c20f86c0201b29d0ba1ff05a58baedcd654/lib/env/index.js#L100-106) will look there first:

```
// We tried using NPM to get the global modules path, but it haven't work out
// because of bugs in the parseable implementation of `ls` command and mostly
// performance issues. So, we go with our best bet for now.
if (process.env.NODE_PATH) {
  _.compact(process.env.NODE_PATH.split(/[;:]/g)).forEach(this.appendPath, this);
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I executed `export NODE_PATH=$HOME/.node/lib/node_modules/` and that indeed seems to solve the issue.

Comment: yo doctor tells you about these things.  Kind of dumb in my opinion, if it has a "doctor" mode, it should run it by default if you have a problem

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a NODE_PATH issue, try to execute the following command:

```
echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc^C
```

Or just type `yo doctor` to figure out what's happening